# Wanting content to overlap header whilst maintaining formatting

Tags: formatting, overlapping

How do I get my content to overlap my header without it being transparent.  I am using simple html and css.

See:

Jean

Answer (score 0):

you can use z-index   and do decoration of your content for not be transparent

Comment: Not very experienced with z-index.  Have tried various options on that with no joy.  I did try z-index: -1; for the image, but that didn't work.

Comment: if you have two blocks and want to overlap once 
you need to specify it z-index in css with positive value
for example 
.xBlock
{
z-index:1000;
}

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realise I had to use the position tag to make it work.